# Problems declaring a 2 dimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

**I have the below code:**

```
    public int[] _SpDep = new int[50];
    public int[][] _SpDepCnt = new int[50][];
    public int[][] _SpReadType = new int[50][];

     _DepNo = Convert.ToInt16(strFileName[n].Substring(1, 2));
     _CntNo = Convert.ToInt16(strFileName[n].Substring(6, 2));
     _SpDep[_DepNo] = 1;
     _SpDepCnt[_DepNo][_CntNo] = 1;
     _SpReadType[_DepNo][_CntNo] = 1;
```

**There's an error when reach this line:**

```
      _SpDepCnt[_DepNo][_CntNo] = 1;
```

But I don't know what's wrong? Any opinions? Is it the `2d array` declare wrongly?

Comment: U mean when I put [50] means the value must be between 0 to 49? I tot I got 50 array values. For example: _DepNo[0], _DepNo[1]....._DepNo[49].

Comment: @Coolguy: Correct, array indicies start at 0, so for 50 values they go from 0..49

Answer (score 5):

### Jagged array `[][]`

If using an array of type `int[][]` (a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)) you want to be initialise your arrays like this:

```
public int[] _SpDep = new int[50];
public int[][] _SpDepCnt = new int[50][];
public int[][] _SpReadType = new int[50][];
```

And then initialise the arrays inside the array:

```
var length = 20;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    _SpDepCnt[i] = new int[length];
     _SpReadType[i] = new int[length];
}
```

It is called a jagged array because the lengths of the second part can vary, you could have this for example:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[5,6]
[7,8,9]
```

### Multidimensional array `[,]`

I believe you want to use the type `int[,]` which is called a [multidimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). They make an array with **two fixed dimensions**.

```
public int[,] _SpDepCnt = new int[50, 20];
public int[][] _SpReadType = new int[50, 20];
```

Multidimensional arrays will create the same sized array for each index:

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]
```

Answer (score 3):

When you declare an "array of arrays" using [][], you need to initialise the outer dimension to reference allocated arrays, like this:

```
public int[][] _SpReadType = new int[50][];

for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
    _SpReadType[i] = new int[SIZE]; // Where you have to decide on SIZE
```

The [][] arrays are also known as "ragged arrays" or "jagged arrays" because the size of each row can be different, since each row is a separate array.

Alternatively, you can use actual 2D arrays using this syntax: [,]

For example:

```
public int[,] _SpReadType = new int[50,SIZE];
```

Then you access the elements like so:

```
int value = _SpReadType[row,col];
```

Comment: I just want an 2d array like this _DepNo[1][1]=1; _DepNo[1][2]=1; Something like that...

Comment: I recommend you use the 2D array syntax, `_DepNo[1,1]=1;` and declare it as `int[,] _DepNo = new int[ROWS,COLS];`

Answer (score 1):

that's a jagged array you have to initialize the element before you can use it

```
myJaggedArray[0] = new int[5];
myJaggedArray[1] = new int[4];
myJaggedArray[2] = new int[2];
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

What you tried is called *[`jagged arrays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)*, not *[`multidimensional arrays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)*.

If you want to use 2 dimennsional array, you can use it like;

```
 public int[,] _SpDepCnt = new int[50, 50];
 _SpDepCnt[_DepNo, _CntNo] = 1;
```

If you want to use *jagged array*, you can use it like;

```
public int[][] _SpReadType = new int[50][];

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    _SpReadType[i] = new int[SIZE];
```

> A jagged array is an array **whose elements are arrays**. The elements of
>   a jagged array can be of different dimensions and sizes. A jagged
>   array is sometimes called an "array of arrays."

Comment: perhaps this should have been a comment

Answer (score 0):

You must reserve memory for the 2D-Array

```
public int[][] _SpDepCnt = new int[50][];
_SpDepCnt[_DepNo] = new int[50];
_SpDepCnt[_DepNo][_CntNo] = 1;
```